# Does a Burkina Faso citizen need a transit visa for Brussels?

Tags: schengen, transit-visas

Does a Burkina Faso citizen need a transit visa for Brussels when traveling to the USA?  She has a USA visa.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can probably transit without a visa.

A [Timatic search using the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/hk/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=BF&NV=Burkina+Faso&DC=US&DV=United+States&TC=BE&TV=Belgium&h=b8f1d7e75c303a3421e4c556ea26c6f3c8a592ba) says:

> Transit - Belgium (BE)
>
> Visa
>   Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

So unless your transit time exceeds 24 hours, you're fine.