# As Burundian national can I "over night transit" throught Brussels from Romania to Burundi (East Africa) without a Schengen Visa?

Tags: transit, schengen-visas, bru, burundian-citizens

I am a Burundian, I have a Romanian Short Stay Visa.  I have bought a round trip ticket through Brussels Airlines from Burundi-Romania/Romania-Burundi. The second itinerary is half operated by Tarom RO (overnight transit in Brussels) and by Brussels Airlines. This situation will require me to claim my luggage once in Brussels (meaning going through immigration) and to check-in (again going through immigration) so that I can wait for my connection fight. Since I won't have a Schengen Visa (Romania is not part of the Schengen zone yet):

1. will I be allowed to claim my luggage and check-in?
2. Will I be allowed to stay overnight at the airport?
3. Tarom Airlines will not register my luggage until the final destination as the waiting time is more than 45 minutes, but since I bought the round trip through Brussels Airlines isn't there a way for these 2 companies to coordinate the whole trip?

Comment: Tarom has [code-share agreement](https://www.tarom.ro/en/partners) with Brussels Air on the Bucharest-Brussels-Bucharest route so I'm pretty sure your luggage should get checked through. Have you talked to Tarom about the weird 45 minute rule?

Comment: Yes I have just called their call center and someone confirmed! But I didn't know about the code-share agreement so I didn't insist on that. Will check again with Tarom. Thank you for this info!

Comment: The answer to (1) is *no.*  Without a Schengen visa you will be unable to pass through passport control.  I think the answer to (2) is *yes,* but I am not certain that the airport is open overnight.  I have no idea about (3).

Comment: Thank you for your reply … Will check on the opening hours of the airport. Do you think it makes sens to look for a transit visa?

Comment: It might make sense to look for a different flight. But I think any other itinerary would require two layovers instead of just one. For example on Qatar airways OTP-DOH-NBO-BJM

Comment: Exactly! other options require two layovers and more than 20h travelling! I am still asking around, will let you all know how it worked out. Many thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: We have a question about brussels transit https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/98268/50234 . The answer there is that TWOV is available for 24 hours. If your luggage gets tagged through, you probably won't need a visa.

Comment: Very helpful, I will look into that. Thank you for the info!

Comment: Hi everyone, just to close this subject by telling you how it worked out. The Code-share agreement between the 2 airlines and the TWOV (Transit without visa) available for 24 hours has solved the problem :))! So I will be able to register my luggage until the final destination (you has to mention this only at the check in) and because my transit time does not exceed 24h I am allowed to stay in the airport and wait for the next connection flight.

Comment: FYI: I have tried to contact by phone the 2 airlines but they didn't known exactly the answer and they gave me wrong information. I had to personally go to the airport at the check-in, show my ticket and I was able to get a correct answer. Anyways, thank you all for your inputs and feedback...it was very helpful!

Comment: Please consider posting your experience as an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

OP hasn't returned to answer, but did post the result in the comments, so I'm turning into an answer.  Happy to remove if they return instead.

> Hi everyone, just to close this subject by telling you how it worked
>   out. The Code-share agreement between the 2 airlines and the TWOV
>   (Transit without visa) available for 24 hours has solved the problem
>   :))! So I will be able to register my luggage until the final
>   destination (you has to mention this only at the check in) and because
>   my transit time does not exceed 24h I am allowed to stay in the
>   airport and wait for the next connection flight.
>
> FYI: I have tried to contact by phone the 2 airlines but they didn't
>   known exactly the answer and they gave me wrong information. I had to
>   personally go to the airport at the check-in, show my ticket and I was
>   able to get a correct answer. Anyways, thank you all for your inputs
>   and feedback...it was very helpful!